# Not getting available bytes from inputstrem

Tags: android

I have program which communicates with serial port 
here is the code for obtaining Bluetooth socket

```
public void ManageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket)
{
    //final byte delimiter;
    mmSocket = socket;
    //  Volt.setText(mmSocket.toString());
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mmSocket.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
    // member streams are final 
    try{
        mmInStream =mmSocket.getInputStream(); 
        mmOutStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    }catch (IOException e){
        //Log exception
    }   
    data(mmSocket);        
}
```

`data()` is a function which obtains the available bytes

```
public void data(BluetoothSocket socket)
{
    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesAvailable=0;

    while(!stopWorker)
    {
        try {
            bytesAvailable = mmInStream.available(); 
            Volt.setText( bytesAvailable);
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Log exception
        }   
        stopWorker = true;
    }//while
}
```

I just try to display the number of bytes available in a an `edittext` volt but it won't show anythig

Comment: Do not, EVER, silently catch and discard exceptions.

Comment: catch(Exception e)
    {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} but not working

Comment: When you run it, is the error being shown through a Toast message?

Comment: ya NoResourceFoundException

Answer (score 0):

InputStream.available() makes very weak guarantees and should not be relied upon for reading the stream.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29

The only way to know how many bytes are there is to read them